# connecting trust wallet mobile to my dapp

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications, trustwallet

I am trying to write a dapp and I need to connect trust wallet app to my dapp programmatically, is it different from below code and connecting to browser desktop?

await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })